# A friend function accessing a private member of a friend class

Tags: c++, friend, friend-function, friend-class

Following [the Czech song from *Eurovision 2019 in Tel-Aviv*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH1-uy9FYKE)

It is known that in C++ a friend of a friend is *not (automatically)* a friend.

Clang however differs on the following code with GCC and MSVC:

```
class A {
public:    
    // forward declaration
    class Inner2;

private:
    class Inner1 {
        char foo;
        friend class Inner2;
    };
public:
    class Inner2 {
        Inner1 i;
    public:
        bool operator==(Inner2 other) {
            return i.foo == other.i.foo; // OK by GCC, Clang and MSVC++
        }
        friend bool operator!=(Inner2 a, Inner2 b) {
            return a.i.foo != b.i.foo; // Clang accepts, GCC and MSVC++ reject
        }
    };
};
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/rn48PTe1Y

Which one is correct?
If Clang is wrong by being too permissive, what is the best way to allow access (other than providing a public getter?)

---

<sub>A note: if the friend function is just declared in the class and implemented outside, [both Clang and GCC reject the code](https://godbolt.org/z/9Y19hWGPE).</sub>

Comment: clang is wrong, since it is allowing `operator!=()`  - which is not a friend of `Inner1` to access private members of `Inner1`.   A way to correctly provide access (which doesn't rely on all compilers having a bug like clang does) would be to make the `operator!=()` a member of `Inner2` rather than a `friend` - since `Inner2` is a `friend` already, its members will correctly have access to members of instances of `Inner1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be [a known defect in clang, bug id #11515](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11515), reported already in 2011, but still not fixed, apparently.

An even simpler example that compiles, and shouldn't (from the bug report above):

```
class A {
  int n;
  friend struct B;
};

struct B {
  friend int get(A &a) {
    return a.n; // clang accepts, and should reject
  }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r78Pazoqj